What is the correct translation of "The Agony in the Garden of Gethsemane"?
I need this for my newest piece of art.
Google AI is saying: "Agonia in Horto Gethsemaniae"
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Not a literal translation, but I believe the best choice in line with Christian/artistic tradition, referring to Christ's Agony in the Garden, would be Oratio in horto Gethsemani.
That means "Prayer in the garden," and that is indeed how the episode is frequently referred to in many languages, e.g. Italian, French and German; in fact, I didn't know the English language deviated from this tradition until I read this question.
If, theoretically, you wanted to translate the English literally (de quo autem desistas obsecro), you could say Maestitia in horto (cf. coepit contristari et moestus esse, Mt 26:37). Dictionaries will suggest things like acerbissimus dolor for "agony." Agonia as a Greek loan is apparently found in Ecclesiastical Latin, but I would avoid it.

"Agonia as a Greek loan is apparently found in Ecclesiastical Latin, but I would avoid it" – well, that was a stupid comment from me. If I had bothered to look up the gospel of Luke, I would have read: (Lk 22:43): Et factus in agonia, prolixius orabat. Also, the Church of all Nations is apparently called the Basilica Agoniae Domini in Latin – so by all means, use agonia in this context over more classical choices like maestitia.

Thanks so much. I'm going to use "Agonia in horto..." Would it be "Gethsemani" or "Gethsemaniae"?

@user3502848 My edition of the vulgate calls it Gethsemani in both the ablative and the nominative, so my guess is that it is a feminine indeclinable noun, Gethsemani.
